# Pass a type to an extension in c#?

Tags: c#, types, extension-methods

In Unity, say you have `class Explosion:MonoBehavior`, using `GetComponent` you can trivially

```
List<Transform> result = new List<Transform>();
foreach (Transform t in here)
    {
    if ( t.GetComponent<Explosion>() )
      result.Add( t );
    }
```

The list now contains any immediate active or inactive children, which have the "Explosion" component.

I want to make an extension which does that, along the lines

```
List<Explosion> = transform.Tricky(typeof(Explosion));
```

So, the extension would look something like ...

```
public static List<Transform> Tricky(this Transform here, Type ttt)
    {
    List<Transform> result = new List<Transform>();
    foreach (Transform t in here)
        {
        if ( t.GetComponent<ttt>() )
            result.Add( t );
        }
    return result;
    }
```

However I have utterly failed to figure this out. How to?

---

## Note!

I do know how to do this with generics:

```
public static List<T> MoreTricky<T>(this Transform here)
  {
  List<T> result = new List<T>();
  foreach (Transform t in here)
      {
      T item = t.GetComponent<T>(); if (item != null) result.Add(item);
      }
  return result;
  }
```

(so, `List<Dog> d = t.MoreTricky<Dog>();`)   Incredibly, I am so lame I don't know how to do it "normally", passing in the type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is pretty easy, you just need to use the version of `GetComponent` that takes in a type as one of its parameters and returns a Component object (`public Component GetComponent(Type type);`), it is the first one listed [in the documentation](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.GetComponent.html). Be aware that in the documentation the example they show in the section for the non-generic overload is for the generic overload, they do not have a example of the non-generic on the page.

```
public static List<Transform> Tricky(this Transform here, Type ttt)
{
    List<Transform> result = new List<Transform>();

    foreach (Transform t in here)
    {
        Component item = t.GetComponent(ttt);
        if (item)
            result.Add(t);
    }
    return result;
}
```

You would call it as like

```
List<Transform> explosionTransfoms = transform.Tricky(typeof(Explosion))
```

Comment: Ahh ... so that's how you do it!  Thanks!